# Dompdf package other languages support in laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, dompdf

i have created my pdf using dompdf package in laravel project. But when i want to render other language (bangla) instead of english

```
????????????????????????????
```

are shown.

```
<body style="font-family: 'AdorshoLipi', Arial, sans-serif !important;">

    <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; margin: 50px;  padding: 10px;">
        <div align="center">
            <h2>
                 Anti-corruption commission hotline-106
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p> Reference No : {{ $complain->call_ref_id }}</p>
            {{-- <br> --}}
            <p> Date : {{ $complain->created_at }}</p>
            <p> Name : {{ $complain->name }}</p>
            <p> Address : {{ $complain->address }}</p>
            <p> Phone Number : {{ $complain->phone_number }}</p>
            <p> Against : {{ $complain->against }}</p>
            <p> Sector : {{ $complain->department }}</p>
            <p style="font-family: 'AdorshoLipi', Arial, sans-serif !important;"> Type : {{ $complain->type }}</p>
            <p> Complain Description : {{ $complain->complain_description }}</p>
            <p> Amount : {{ $complain->amount }}</p>
            <p> Status : {{ $complain->status }}</p>


        </div>

        <div style=" margin-left: 450px; width: 100px; ">
            <hr>
            <label>Signature</label>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-primary">

        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Are you using [laravel Dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) package?

Comment: Yes, i am using laravel Dompdf.

Comment: hope you included your font file and setup `@font-face`?

Comment: <style>

  @font-face {
   font-family: 'AdorshoLipi';
   src: url('{{public_path()}}/storage/fonts/AdorshoLipi.ttf')  format('truetype')
  }

  body{
   font-family: 'AdorshoLipi',  sans-serif, !important;
  }


 </style>I added the above code into my pdf file but it didn't work.

Comment: Check my answer and follow given steps, Hope you find the solution.

Comment: Any warnings or errors from PHP? Seems like your font reference is valid. Could be that dompdf is unable to update the font metrics information. Did you create the font directory under app/storage?

Answer (score 3):

You can add support with your *TrueType* font into laravel [Dompdf package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). Just follow below steps to load *TrueType* font into dompdf from the command line.

There are basic two methods to use *TrueType* font family with this package:
**1) Using load_font.php script

2) Using @font-face css rules to load a font at run-time**

**1) Using load_font.php script**
*load_font.php* is a script which run using command line so you need to run the command from the command line. You can easily get this script from [Dompdf utils](https://github.com/dompdf/utils)

Once this utility added, run command below command into your command line interface to install the font from your dompdf installation directory.

```
php load_font.php font_family /pathto/fontfile.ttf
```

**Note:** dompdf currently supports only *TrueType* fonts. So when looking for a font make sure it comes in TrueType format.

**2) Using `@font-face` css rules to load a font at run-time**
You just need to add below style script into your page for use *TrueType* of font.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font_family';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url(http://example.com/fonts/fontfile.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Once above font family loaded, you can use it like: `<div style="font-family: font_family, sans-serif;">yourtextinotherlanguage</div>`

Make sure that your document specify that using UTF-8 like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`.

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo#load-a-font-supporting-your-characters-into-dompdf) too

Comment: @Md.SukelAli: Hope you get something from my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd. 
After run php command my result is different than usual result. 
Usual Result:
 
Unable to find bold face file.
Unable to find italic face file.
Unable to find bold_italic face file.
Copying /home/fonts/firefly.ttf to /home/dompdf/lib/fonts/firefly.ttf...
Generating .afm for /home/dompdf/fonts/firefly.ttf...
?
Finished - font files created.

My Result:

Copying SolaimanLipi_29-05-06.ttf to storage/fonts/SolaimanLipi_29-05-06.ttf...
Generating Adobe Font Metrics for storage/fonts/SolaimanLipi_29-05-06
The Path is different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code within the styles tag in the view file

```
  @font-face {
            font-family: 'iskpota';
            src: url('{{public_path()}}/fonts/your-font.ttf') format('truetype') 
        }
        body{
            font-family: 'your-font', sans-serif; 
        }
```

Then you need to have the font file included in the storage directory. For that, create a folder named "fonts" right inside the storage folder and include the "your-font.ttf" file within the fonts folder.

PS. These fonts you add in the storage location should also be available in the public/fonts folder.

Comment: already used font face rules. Lets example:Text should be আমি comes out like আ ম ি

Answer (score -1):

For a better to use different languages like bangla, you can try to used mpf. This one is good for utf8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really don't want to use another package and i am not very familiar with your suggested package.

Answer (score -4):

Try to decode your output with utf8:

```
utf8_decode($var)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i can't understand the answer. Can you elaborate your answer please.

Comment: I had a problem that some characters could't be shown. an example: ä was shown as a star if i remember correctly. I used UTF-8 to fix the problem. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). So thats why i suggested to use the "utf8_decode" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php).

Comment: Ensuring proper encoding is important, but you really shouldn't ever use `utf8_decode`. It re-encodes your text into iso-8859-1, any characters not supported by that encoding are converted to question marks.